# Java Regex match to avoid splitting

Tags: java, regex

I'm reading a text file that has multiple lines like below.

```
key1:Combine(val -> [{"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"}])
key2:Combine(val -> [{"id":"211","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"223","pid":"sdDfsd"}])
key3:Combine(val -> [{"id":"423","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"454","pid":"sdDfsd"}])
```

For each line I need to create a map that has `key` and the Json string as the val.

For example for the above example I would need my map to be like this

map1 = `key1`,`{"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"}`

map2 = `key2`,`{"id":"211","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"223","pid":"sdDfsd"}`

map3 = `key3`,`{"id":"423","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"454","pid":"sdDfsd"}`

Im using the split approach like below and strip the last 2 chars of the second val.

```
String[] temp = str.split(":Combine(val -> [");
```

Im trying to create regex pattern match to exract these key and val which I need help on

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of many possible solutions.

```
String[] strs = {
        "key1:Combine(val -> [{\"id\":\"123\",\"pid\":\"Xd34d\"},{\"id\":\"124\",\"pid\":\"sdDfsd\"}])",
        "key2:Combine(val -> [{\"id\":\"211\",\"pid\":\"Xd34d\"},{\"id\":\"223\",\"pid\":\"sdDfsd\"}])",
        "key3:Combine(val -> [{\"id\":\"423\",\"pid\":\"Xd34d\"},{\"id\":\"454\",\"pid\":\"sdDfsd\"}])" };
```

Here is one way to parse it.  And you can apply it in a stream to make it easy to build the map.  The `key` and `value` would end up in `group1` and `group2` below.

- `(.*?):`  reluctant capture of characters up to first `:`
- `.*?\\[`  reluctant skipping of characters up to and including first `[`
- `(.*})`   capture of remaining characters up to and including last `}`

```
String regex = "(.*?):Combine.*?\\[(.*})";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

Map<String, String> results = Arrays.stream(strs)
        .flatMap(st -> p.matcher(st).results())
        .collect(Collectors
                .toMap(m -> m.group(1), m -> m.group(2)));

results.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
key1={"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"}
key2={"id":"211","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"223","pid":"sdDfsd"}
key3={"id":"423","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"454","pid":"sdDfsd"}
```

Comment: The regex looks fine but im wondering what if the key has a `:` in it by itself

Comment: I modified my answer to focus on the regex.  I also included a stream solution employing said regex to build the map.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a pattern and matcher with the regex that you require like so:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("val -> (.*)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
matcher.results().forEach((match) -> {
    System.out.println(match.group(1));
});
```

Will output:

```
[{"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"}]
[{"id":"211","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"223","pid":"sdDfsd"}]
[{"id":"423","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"454","pid":"sdDfsd"}]
```

To convert the Json I can only recommend using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and parse it through that using by creating a class for it like:

```
Class GenericItem {
    Public Integer id;
    Public String pid;
}

Class ListOfGenericItems {
    List<GenericItem> items;
}
```

Then using gson to turn the results into something more usable:

```
var key1 = new Gson.fromJson(match.group(1), ListOfGenericItems.class);
```

This way if you wish to use the data you can use

```
key1.items(0).id; //get id of result of first group on key 1
key1.items(1).pid; //get pid of result of second group on key 1
```

@WJS did have a better answer for the regex pattern however, mine will only return the json values theirs will bring the first key as well if you wanted to use that to identify key of groups.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using split:

Used regex:

```
"^(\\w+):Combine\\(val -> \\[(.*)\\]"
```

Split in context:

```
/**
 * Content of inputFile.txt:
 * key1:Combine(val -> [{"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"}])
 * key2:Combine(val -> [{"id":"211","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"223","pid":"sdDfsd"}])
 * key3:Combine(val -> [{"id":"423","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"454","pid":"sdDfsd"}])
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\myUserName\\Desktop\\inputFile.txt"; // windows file system
    List<String> linesFromInputFile = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(fileName));

    Pattern replacePattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+):Combine\\(val -> \\[(.*)\\]");
    Pattern splitPattern = Pattern.compile("#");

    Map<String, String> mapResult = linesFromInputFile.stream()
            .map(line -> replacePattern.matcher(line).replaceFirst("$1#$2"))
            .map(replacedLine -> splitPattern.split(replacedLine))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0], arr -> arr[1]));

    // Print output
    mapResult.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
            .forEach(entry -> System.out.printf("Key: '%s' => Value: '%s'%n"
                    , entry.getKey()
                    , entry.getValue()));
}
```

Output:

```
Key: 'key1' => Value: '{"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"})'
Key: 'key2' => Value: '{"id":"211","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"223","pid":"sdDfsd"})'
Key: 'key3' => Value: '{"id":"423","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"454","pid":"sdDfsd"})'
```

Answer (score 0):

You indicated you wanted to avoid splitting but in your post you show an example of using `split` so I thought I would address that with the following.  You can split on multiple string using the alternation `(|)` operator.  In the following case the split would produce an array of size `3`.  Only the first two values would be used as key and value.

```
String regex = ":Combine.*?\\[|(?:\\])";

String s = 
  "key1:Combine(val -> [{\"id\":\"123\",\"pid\":\"Xd34d\"},{\"id\":\"124\",\"pid\":\"sdDfsd\"}])";

String [] parts = s.split(regex);
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("parts[%d] -> %s%n", i, parts[i]);
}
```

prints

```
parts[0] -> key1
parts[1] -> {"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"}
parts[2] -> )
```

And using in a stream to create a map

```
key1={"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"}
key2={"id":"211","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"223","pid":"sdDfsd"}
key3={"id":"423","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"454","pid":"sdDfsd"}


Map<String, String> results = Arrays.stream(strs)
        .map(st -> st.split(regex))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a[0], a -> a[1]));

results.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
key1={"id":"123","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"124","pid":"sdDfsd"}
key2={"id":"211","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"223","pid":"sdDfsd"}
key3={"id":"423","pid":"Xd34d"},{"id":"454","pid":"sdDfsd"}
```